# XACML Authentication in Network Proxy Server

Tags: authentication, caching, proxy

I am trying to implement Access Control Policies on Network Proxy Server. Presently, I am at a stage where I have modeled it like this:

[image]

The problem I am facing is how to send the resource url, username and password from PEP to PDP. I am presently using WSO2 for implementing PDP policies.

Relating to this I also saw a command on [this link](http://www.webfarmr.eu/2013/04/how-to-send-a-xacml-request-using-curl/), which is as follow:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:text/xml' -T soap-xacml-request.xml https://localhost:8443/asm-pdp/pdp --cacert pdp.b64.cer --user pep:password`

I also don't know what url should I be giving instead of `https://localhost:8443/asm-pdp/pdp` (as I am using WSO2).

Can somebody please help me regarding all these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the WSO2 documentation and blog? E.g. http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/06/14/pep-client-for-wso2is-pdp/.